# saving kafka messages consumed by spark streaming in zeppelin notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zeppelin

I have problem saving kafka messages consumed by spark streaming in zeppelin notebook.

My code is:

```
case class Message(id: Long, message: String, timestamp: Long) extends Serializable

   val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

  val messagesStream = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, 
    Map("zookeeper.connect" -> "localhost:2181", "group.id" -> "test-consumer-group"),
    Map("test" -> 4),
    StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    .map { case (k, v) =>  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats; JsonMethods.parse(v).extract[Message] }
    .filter(_.id % 2 == 0)

  val mes =  messagesStream.window(Seconds(10))

  mes
  .map(m => Message(m.id, m.message, m.timestamp))
  .foreachRDD( rdd => rdd.toDF.registerTempTable("messages"))

  ssc.start()
```

When i run `%sql select * from messages` it shows no data, but the table is defined. If i change saving to tempTable on Cassandra it saves and shows data correctly. Don't understand why it is so.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the problem. Let's first review the foreachRDD operator definition :

`foreachRDD` is not used how it's intended to be used. It is the most generic output operator that applies a function, func, to each RDD generated from the stream. This function should push the data in each RDD to an **external system,** such as saving the RDD to files, or writing it over the network to a database. Note that the function func is executed in the driver process running the streaming application, and will usually have RDD actions in it that will force the computation of the streaming RDDs.

So what's actually happening with your code is the following :

Since DStreams are executed lazily by the output operations, just like RDDs are lazily executed by RDD actions. Specifically, RDD actions inside the DStream output operations force the processing of the received data. *Hence, if your application does not have any output operation, which you don't, or has output operations like dstream.foreachRDD() without any RDD action inside them, then nothing will get executed. The system will simply receive the data and discard it*.

So your RDD data are discarded each time you perform `registerTempTable` and so your SQL query gives an empty result.

To solve your problem, you'll need to save your data somewhere (Cassandra is a good choice) then query on it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid another cluster: another solution would be to convert rdd to row and then to df and then save it to hdfs as a parquet or orc with option to append the file ex:

```
write.format("orc").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("id").save("/tmp/data")
```

I am just wondering how come AWS bloggers were able to perform analysis directly on temp table re [enter link description here][1]

good thing is that structured streaming is coming soon :)

[1]:aws blog: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3K805CZ8WFBRP/Analyze-Realtime-Data-from-Amazon-Kinesis-Streams-Using-Zeppelin-and-Spark-Stream

Comment: i wonder if it is possible to convert  DStream rdd to write.stream , does anyone know?